# clique em campo texto jquery

Tags: jquery

Como faço para logo que minha pagina iniciar, for dado um clique em um campo texto?

Quero fazer com *jQuery*

Comment: Quando você diz "clicar" não seria "focus"? Ou seja, o utilizador pode digitar qualquer coisa sem a necessidade de clicar sobre o input, uma vez que o foco já está atribuído ao input.

Comment: nao o .click mesmo, eu estou com um problema no campo de login e senha, ao iniciar o site, o place-holder dos campos sobem para dar lugar ao texto digitado, porem o do campo senha nao está subindo, somente quando da um clique no campo o efeito acontece, acontece que quem deixa usuario e senha salvos e os campos ja vem preenchidos entao nao foi dado esse "clique", entao vem em cima do texto, nao sei se conseguiu entender kkkk

Comment: Estás a utilizar o materializecss?

Comment: Poste o seu código para podermos compreender e simular seu problema. Pesquise por `$("#campo").trigger("click");` talvez te ajude http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Pelo visto vc está utilizando Materialize certo? É mais fácil vc tentar resolver pq o framework não está subindo o label (placeholder), do que fazer uma função para subir o mesmo. Só o campo senha não está subindo ou login tbm? No site do Materialize eu fiz um teste e deu certo. Dei um clique no input subiu o label para cima e então preenchi, aí fui para outra página, dei um voltar e os campos estavam preenchidos e com o label já em cima, não seria alguma erro no seu código?

Comment: Entao Leandro, nao entendo o Login funciona normalmente, logo que executo o site, o label usuario sobe pois o campo ja vem preechido, porem a senha nao sobe, só após o clique dentro do campo texto... Nao tem erro no codigo pois nao alterei nada, somente copiei e colei o html pronto. Não estou usando o materialize nao, estou usando esse exemplo https://colorlib.com/etc/lf/Login_v2/index.html

Comment: Dei uma olhada no link, como vc está utilizando isto, é um plugin?

Comment: Se vc analisar, clica no link, preenche o usuario e da um enviar e depois clica em voltar, o label vai ficar em cima do conteudo digitado tb igual ta ficando pra mim, nao sei se seria bug do navegador mas creio que nao

Comment: Sim verdade, então pq está utilizando isto? Já que vc quer utilizar este efeito no formulário utilize o Materiallize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur se vc puder utilizar frameworks css para a aplicação da para utilizar assim com Materiallize:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="icon_prefix">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="icon_telephone" type="tel" class="validate">
          <label for="icon_telephone">Telephone</label>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
</div>
```